# Giving another class variablevalues before the variables are declared in Java

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to pass values to variables that probably are not declared yet.
From my main source class I am giving another's class some values, but later on it seems like the values are gone.

## **Source code:**

**server.java (main):**

```
public class server {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    //Print a simple message to the user to notify there is something going on...
    System.out.println("Starting server, please wait...");

    //Connecting all class files to the server.
    filehandler filehandlerclass = new filehandler();
    networking networkingclass = new networking();
    //End of class files connecting.

    //Preparing the filehandler's file information to open a new filestream.
    filehandlerclass.filetohandlename = "server";
    filehandlerclass.filetohandleextention = "ini";
    filehandlerclass.filetohandlepath = "configs\\";

    //Request a new filestream using the filehandler's file variables.
    filehandlerclass.openfilestream(filehandlerclass.filestream, filehandlerclass.filetohandle);

    //Checks if the filehandler has tried to open a filestream.
    if(filehandlerclass.filestreamopen == true) {
        //Request a check if the filestream was opened sucessfully.
        filehandlerclass.filestreamexists(filehandlerclass.filestream);
    }
    //If the filehandler has not tried to open a filestream...
    else    {
        System.out.println("Error: The filehandler does not seem to have tried to open a filoestream yet.");
        System.out.println("A possibility is that the server could not call the method from the filehandler properly.");
    }

    //Checks if the boolean "filestreamexists" from the filehandlerclass is true.
    if(filehandlerclass.filestreamexists(filehandlerclass.filestream) == true)  {
        //The filestream seems to exist, let's read the file and extract it's information.
        filehandlerclass.readfile(filehandlerclass.filestream);
    }
    else    {
        filehandlerclass.openfilestream(filehandlerclass.filestream, filehandlerclass.filetohandle);
    }
}
}
```

**filehandler.java:**

```
//Imports the java.io library so the filehandler can read and write to text files.
import java.io.*;

public class filehandler    {

//Variables for the filehandler class.
public String filetohandlename;
public String filetohandleextention;
public String filetohandlefullname = filetohandlename + "." + filetohandleextention;
public String filetohandlepath;
public String filetohandle = filetohandlepath + filetohandlefullname;

//Boolean that is true if the filehandler's "openfilestream"-method has tried to open a filestream.
//Is false as long as none filestreams have been touched.
public boolean filestreamopen = false;

//Declares a variable for the filestream to access text files.
public File filestream;
//End of variable list.

//Called to open a filestream so the server can load properties from text files.
public void openfilestream(File filestream, String filetohandle)    {

    //Tell the user that a filestream is about to be opened.
    System.out.println("Opening filestream for \"" + filetohandlefullname + "\"...");
    //Open a filestream called "filestream" using the variable "filetohandle"'s value
    //as information about wich file to open the filestream for.
    filestream = new File(filetohandle);
    //Turn the boolean "filestreamopen" to true so next time the server checks it's
    //value, it knows if the filehandler has tried to open a filestream.
    filestreamopen = true;
}

//Boolean that checks if the filestream exists.
public boolean filestreamexists(File filestream)    {
    //Tell the user that a check on the filestream is going on.
    System.out.println("Checking if filestream for \"" + filetohandlefullname + "\" exists...");
    //If the filestream exists...
    if(filestream.exists()) {
        //Tell the user that the filestream exists.
        System.out.println("Filestream for \"" + filetohandlefullname + "\" exists!");
        //Make the boolean's value positive.
        return true;
    }
    //If the filestream does not exist...
    else    {
        //Tell the user that the filestream does not exist.
        System.out.println("Filestream for \"" + filetohandlefullname + "\" does not exist!");
        //Make the boolean's value negative.
        return false;
    }
}

//Called to read files and collect it's information.
public void readfile(File filestream)   {
    //Checks if the file that is going to be read is a configuration file.
    if(filetohandleextention == "ini")  {
        //Tell the user that a configuration file is going to be read.
        System.out.println("Extracting information from the configuration file \"" + filetohandle + "\".");
    }
}
}
```

**networking.java:**

```
public class networking {

}
```

## **Problem:**

server.java is going to serve commands to the source files and tell them what to do.
The source files are not going to act on their own unless server.java has given them a command.
This way I am planning to be able to write simple function calls in server.java to do greater tasks from the different source files.

server.java seems to pass the variables "filetohandlename", "filetohandleextention" and "filetohandlepath" before the variables are declared and when they get declared, they are declared with "null" as value.

## **Result:**

[image: Java compile/run error.]

I get no errors when I compile it.
All I think is happening is a miss match with giving the variables that specifies the file that is going to be read's proper values.
It also throws an exception which I have not been careing to look into for now, either it's because "null.null" does not exist or that I wrote the code wrong.

## **Final request:**

Does anybody know if I can make a method for recieving the variables values
or if there is another more proper way around?
Could I probably make an array of the variables in server.java and collect the values from that array?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You should really learn to use camel case for your Java code. fileStreamOpen, for example. Also, Java classes should begin with a capital letter.

Comment: camel case is god damn important

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
public String filetohandlename;
public String filetohandleextention;
public String filetohandlefullname = filetohandlename + "." + filetohandleextention;
```

initialises the first two variables to null, and the third to "null.null". Note that if you change one of the component variables that have made up `filetohandlefullname`, it won't then change the value of `filetohandlefullname`. If you want that to happen, then `filetohandlefullname` should be replaced by a method performing the appending operation.

This:

```
public void openfilestream(File filestream, String filetohandle)
```

passes a different variable `filetohandle` into the method. That variable is *distinct* from `this.filetohandle`.

I think there's a numberof issues with this code (above) and I'd do the following.

1. replace variables instantiated via other variables with methods that perform this dynamically. That way, when you change `var1` that you'd expect to change the value of `var2`, that will happen automatically via a method return. e.g create a private method `getFileToHandleFullName()` and bin the corresponding variable
2. scope class members with `this`
3. where possible, make those members `final` so you don't *inadvertently* change them

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
public String filetohandlefullname = filetohandlename + "." + filetohandleextention;
```

is executed when you instantiate the class (ie `filehandler filehandlerclass = new filehandler();`).  At that point in time both variables are unset, thus `filetohandlefullname` is initialized to `null.null`

But there's a number of other problems with your code as well, like

```
//Request a new filestream using the filehandler's file variables.
filehandlerclass.openfilestream(filehandlerclass. filestream,filehandlerclass.filetohandle);
```

eg you're passing parameters that are fields from the same instance.  That's totally useless as the method already has access to those, and it's very confusing.

And maybe slightly controversial:

```
//Make the boolean's value positive.
return true;
```

Comments are only useful if they clarify code that without them would be less obvious, and they have to be 100% true and not, as happens so often, what the program wishes the code would do.   In this specific case neither of these conditions is fulfilled as the comment doesn't clarify what's going on, and actually the method's return value is set, not some nondescript "boolean's value"